# How to remove commands installed through the "command-not-found" prompt

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf, command-not-found

On Fedora 35, if I type in a command that is not installed, like `mu`, then I get a prompt that offers to install it for me, i.e.

```
mu
bash: mu: command not found...
Install package 'maildir-utils' to provide command 'mu'? [N/y]
```

My question is: How can I uninstall packages that are installed this way, as `dnf remove mu` does not work. Logically enough, I currently get the following output:

```
No match for argument: mu
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall a “command” installed as a result of the command-not-found prompt, the general approach is to determine which package provides the command, and remove that.

Run

```
rpm -q --whatprovides $(command -v foo)
```

to check that the package makes sense, then

```
sudo dnf remove $(rpm -q --whatprovides $(command -v foo))
```

to remove it, along with any dependencies which are no longer needed.